# How do I know which version of MDAC is installed?

Tags: mdac

How can I find out which version of MDAC is installed on a computer?

Comment: Doesn't this probably belong on http://superuser.com?

Comment: @Derek, I think this is on topic, as it such a big issue when writing installers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to check for MDAC version](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=301202)